# Ignore assembly .dll in same folder as executable

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac, mysql.data

I have a .NET application that crashes if I have the MySql.Data.dll assembly in the same folder as the executable but works fine if I move it. A different executable in the same folder is dependent on it so I need to keep it there.

What can I do to make the app ignore this dll?
I assume I can edit the config file but I can't seem to find anyone having had the problem of ignoring a local .dll, so I don't know what to write.

What makes me even more confused is the part about loaded assemblies written in the details of the exception. Mind you the file in the local folder (the one I want to ignore) is versioned 6.9.9.0 and the exception states that it wants to load 6.9.5.0 where as the loaded one (from the GAC) is 6.9.8.0.

This is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DB" connectionString="*" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Very thankful for any help.

```
************** Loaded Assemblies **************
---------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.9.8.0
    Win32 Version: 6.9.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/v4.0_6.9.8.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
```

---

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>       File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>          at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataAssemblyHelper.SafeLoadReferencedAssembly(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName)
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataAssemblyHelper.d__8.MoveNext()
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.GetAllDiscoverableAssemblies()
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.DefaultAssemblyResolver.GetWildcardAssemblies()
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String
>   assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry,
>   MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String
>   path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension,
>   ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path,
>   ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1
>   uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
>          at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)
>          at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0()
>          at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
>          at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
>          at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean
>   initializeAllCollections)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
>          at Panola.Data.Models.PanolaDB..ctor()
>          at Panola.Data.Services.PanolaConfigurator..ctor(String Name, Boolean UseDefualtRepositories)
>          at Panola.Data.Services.PanolaConfigurator..ctor(String Name)
>          at Panola.Tools.Configurator.MainForm.connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e,
>   ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Could you share your `app.config` or `web.config` file?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="*" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is assembly binding; it tries multiple locations, including the local folder and GAC. It is very hard to suppress this. I suspect, however, that the best option here is to add an assembly-binding redirect in the config file, to tell "fusion" to allow 6.9.9.0 in place of previous versions. For example:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Would this need to be surrounded by `<runtime><assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"></assemblybinding></runtime>`?

Comment: @YousifTouma yes, I would being terse

Comment: This did unfortunately not work. Nothing changed in the exception output.

Comment: @YousifTouma hmmm, that's curious; it should, assuming the binding change made it into the exe config. Not sure what to advise there, without seeing it in front of me

Comment: Current state of config:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="*" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
<runtime><assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"><dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblybinding></runtime></configuration>`

Comment: What is also peculiar is that it works on a different installation WITH the dll in the same folder. The difference there is that there is a different connector .net installed (6.9.5 actually). I guess it could work to reinstall the connector on this installation to 6.9.5 also but I fail to see the logic in why that would even help considering moving the local dll file helps this problem?

Comment: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.10.0" newVersion="6.9.10.0" />`
works for me